# cannot import name 'TfidfVectorizer' from 'sklearn.feature_extraction'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf, topic-modeling, tfidfvectorizer

I am trying to do a Topic modeling project, but when I use

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction import TfidfVectorizer
```

I will receive this error, my sckit-learn version installed is 0.24.1. I will be grateful if anyone could help me.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-5ae89ed22b7e> in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn.feature_extraction import TfidfVectorizer

ImportError: cannot import name 'TfidfVectorizer' from 'sklearn.feature_extraction' (C:\Users\mozha\Anaconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to import vectorizers like `TfidfVectorizer` from `sklearn.feature_extraction.text` and not `sklearn.feature_extraction`.